# How to write in Scala shortly "filter first/last n elements satisfying a given function"?

Tags: scala

How to write shortly in Scala "filter out first/last n elements of a sequence satisfying a given function"?

FilterNot is defined:

```
def filterNot(p: A => Boolean): Repr
```

So I'm looking for function like:

```
def filterNotFirst(p: A => Boolean, n: Int): Repr
```

Preferably so that too big n does not throw exception.

Comment: What's `Repr`? Are you filtering on a collection?

Comment: Yes a sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Scala collections library doesn't provide an operation that does exactly this, but there is an idiomatic way to write it: combine `filter` or `filterNot` and `take` or `takeRight`:

```scala
scala> val elems: Seq[Int] = 0 to 100
elems: Seq[Int] = Range 0 to 100

scala> elems.filterNot(_ < 10).take(5)
res0: Seq[Int] = Vector(10, 11, 12, 13, 14)

scala> elems.filterNot(_ < 10).takeRight(5)
res1: Seq[Int] = Vector(96, 97, 98, 99, 100)
```

This won't throw exceptions if `n` is larger than the number of available values:

```
scala> (0 to 15).filterNot(_ < 10).take(100)
res3: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

If you really want `filterNotFirst` as a method, you can define it yourself:

```
def filterNotFirst[A](elems: Seq[A])(p: A => Boolean, n: Int): Seq[A] =
  elems.filterNot(p).take(n)
```

Or even:

```
scala> implicit class FilterNotFirstOp[A](elems: Seq[A]) {
     |   def filterNotFirst(p: A => Boolean, n: Int): Seq[A] =
     |     elems.filterNot(p).take(n)
     | }
defined class FilterNotFirstOp
```

And then:

```
scala> (0 to 15).filterNotFirst(_ < 10, 100)
res4: Seq[Int] = Vector(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
```

I'd suggest just using `filterNot` and `take` where needed, though.